# Why isn't possible to have contravariant return types

Tags: java, generics, contravariance

I'm playing around with generics in Java, and I found something strange:

The following does compile:

```
public static <A, B extends A> B reduce(Function2<A, A, B> func)
{  
   //code doesn't matter
}
```

But the following does not:

```
public static <A, B super A> B reduce(Function2<A, A, B> func)
{  
   //code doesn't matter
}
```

It seems to me the above is perfectly valid (after all, that's pretty much the signature of the reduce method in the Scala Collections).

Why Java doesn't allow contravariant return types, specially in this case, since the return is going to be inferred (by the third argument of Function2)?